# check radio button with no ID, just name, type, value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select some radio button on a webpage using Javascript inside Tampermonkey. For this particular button, there is no element ID, so I'm not really sure how to select them.

There's really no other identifying elements for these buttons that I can see.

Note: There's several radio buttons on this page, and the only unique identifier between them is the "value." There are 12 other buttons, but I want these 3 selected by default after the page loads.

```
<input  name="Offense" type="radio" value="Indifferent">
<input  name="Likelihood" type="radio" value="Indifferent">
<input  name="Humor" type="radio" value="Indifferent">
```

So, I tried to catch them all at once with this:

```
document.getElementByValue("Indifferent").checked = true;
```

but it's not doing anything, I'm sure I'm missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you identify what you need by parents maybe?

Comment: So simply use their names … `getElementsByName`, jQuery (or `querySelectorAll`) and attribute selector, … and then loop through the elements for each name, and check if the value matches. (Or use two attribute selectors, for the name and for the value, that will get you each in one step. Or all three in one, if those are the only elements with that value, then selecting by that would suffice.)

Comment: Or maybe just use: `<input  name="Offense" type="radio" value="Indifferent" checked>` (See the "checked" part)

Comment: Tried 3in1 like CBroe suggested, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Using `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` from [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) returns a NodeList of matching DOM Nodes. Since it is not an Array, a for-loop is used:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Indifferent"]');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

---

The same in jQuery:

```
$('input[value="Indifferent"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// list will contain all the radio buttons
var list = $('input[value="Indifferent"]')


$.each(list, function(index, value) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

All the data you need will be in the value object

https://jsfiddle.net/o46rhpwL/

And if you are looking for the checked value in the list

https://jsfiddle.net/z73ah82b/